# Windows Batch Variable inside variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm not very good at code, but I'm trying to get something to work, which would make my life easier.

I need to get a variable to run from within a variable, if possible, but can't get it to work out.

```
set MAP1=Esseker
set %MAP1%MODS=@exile
-mod=%%MAP1%mods%
```

This is not the full code, but it's just a section showing what it is I am trying to do. `-mod=` is correct as it's part of a startup parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [enabling delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Here's an example script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set MAP1=Esseker
set %MAP1%MODS=@exile
echo !%MAP1%MODS!
-mod=!%MAP1%MODS!
@echo on
```

Not sure if that -mod line should be a set, but I've copied what you had above, making the assumption that it's correct.